# How to manually create a correct primary key for models of a database

Tags: python, mysql, django

My problem is somewhat similar to what is discussed here:
[Django automatically create primary keys for existing database tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585074/django-automatically-create-primary-keys-for-existing-database-tables)

But instead of simple `python manage.py inspectdb` I did `python manage.py inspectdb --include-views`. 
And my problem is with those classes based on views- I get `Error 1054, ("Unknown column 'station_measurements_with_data.id' in 'field list'")`

I've tried to simply add `id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)` to the model, but no joy.

The model class looks like this:

```
class StationMeasurementsWithData(models.Model):
    station_id = models.IntegerField()
    measurement_id = models.IntegerField()
    time_utc = models.DateTimeField()
    pollution_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    measurement_value = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False  # Created from a view. Don't remove.
        db_table = 'station_measurements_with_data'
```

And the view data int the database looks like this:

```
# station_id, measurement_id, time_utc, pollution_name, measurement_value
955, 87318, 2012-01-01 02:00:00, pm2.5, 73
955, 87318, 2012-01-01 02:00:00, pm10, 308
956, 87319, 2012-01-01 02:00:00, pm2.5, 123
956, 87319, 2012-01-01 02:00:00, pm10, 152
957, 87320, 2012-01-01 02:00:00, pm2.5, 163
957, 87320, 2012-01-01 02:00:00, pm10, 198
```

If any column contained unique values I would just make it a primary key, but there isn't one. What should I do in this case?

Comment: `id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)` should have worked. Do you have the error that it gave out? Did you migrate your DB after adding the new column?

Comment: Error is exactly the same.
Do you mean commands 
```python manage.py makemigrations```
```python manage.py migrate
```?

Answer (score 0):

`inspectdb` management command only generates models reflecting tables and views in the database it is run against.

> Adding an automatic primary key field to the model if you don’t declare it. To avoid confusion for later code readers, it’s recommended to specify all the columns from the database table you are modeling when using unmanaged models.
>   
> *Reference*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#managed

I suggest recreating the view that includes an `id` field.

You can imitate an auto-incrementing ids using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function over the result set if your database server is `postgresql` or find another way for your specific database server. *e.g.*

```sql
CREATE VIEW v_foo AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, [[rest fields]]  FROM foo;
```

Comment: Altering the database- that's an idea I'd like to avoid (even though I could do it), because I'm quite happy with how it looks like now.
Also: I use MySQL which supporty ROW_NUM() since version 8.0, but I use 5.7.14. I can still emulate ROW_NUM() function, but it's imho very dirty.

Comment: I don't see how you can proceed without altering the view. Django models are for managing database tables. If you find that rows are unique across your view, you can compute an id field that is an md5 hash of each column.

Comment: Allright @Oluwafemi Sule, let's say I can give up on views.
But I still need the data they provide. What should I do? Copy-paste SELECTs into Python?

Comment: I'm not saying to give up on views.They are not without their benefits. I'm suggesting to alter the view so that it has an id field. You can keep the models for writing the queries. The compromise being that they stay as read-only models

Comment: I tried that idea with md5 and it worked
BUT
it also killed already not so good preformace (fetching all rows takes around 18 sec. instead of around 8). Any cheaper idea?